# Get X amount of latest entries with different attributes SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have the following table:

```
UserId | FileId | Version | Date
-------------------------------------
UserA  | FileA  | Version1| 1.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version2| 2.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version3| 2.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version3| 3.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version3| 4.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version4| 5.1.2016
UserB  | FileA  | Version2| 3.1.2016
```

And I want to get the latest two versions for each user and file that were  created before the 4.1.2016, so the result should look like this:

```
UserId | FileId | Version | Date
-------------------------------------
UserA  | FileA  | Version2| 2.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version3| 3.1.2016    
UserB  | FileA  | Version2| 3.1.2016
```

What would be the correct SQL statement to get this result?

At the moment, I am trying something like this

```
WITH FindNewestVersion AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Date AS cDate, UserId AS UId, 
        FileId AS FId, Version AS Ver,   
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, FileId, Version ORDER BY Created DESC)rn 
    FROM 
        Table
    WHERE 
        Created <= [DATE]
)
SELECT * 
FROM Table AS q 
INNER JOIN (SELECT cDate, UId, FId, Ver 
            FROM FindNewestVersion 
            WHERE rn <= 2) AS x ON q.UserId = UId 
                                AND q.Date = cDate 
                                AND q.FileId = FId 
                                AND q.Version = Ver
GROUP BY q.UserId, q.FileId, q.Date, q.Version
```

But that statement is not quite correct, because it returns this result

```
UserId | FileId | Version | Date
-------------------------------------
UserA  | FileA  | Version1| 1.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version2| 2.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version3| 2.1.2016
UserA  | FileA  | Version3| 3.1.2016    
UserB  | FileA  | Version2| 3.1.2016
```

So, I don't want the first row (with Version1) because there are already two other younger versions and I don't want the entry with Version3 from 2.1.2016 because there is the same entry from 3.1.2016 which is closer to my entered Date parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

#### Attention: Avoid culture-specific Date formats!

I use a CTE to add a column to the set which is numbered for each UserId `DESC` sorted by the date.

#### Attention2: I just saw, that one user might have two entries with the same date. You might include the *Version* to the `OVER(... ORDER BY ...)`

The *real* `SELECT` cuts the set for those which are numbered with 1 or 2

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(UserId VARCHAR(100),FileId VARCHAR(100),Version VARCHAR(100),[Date] DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('UserA','FileA','Version1','1.1.2016')
,('UserA','FileA','Version2','2.1.2016')
,('UserA','FileA','Version3','2.1.2016')
,('UserA','FileA','Version3','3.1.2016')
,('UserA','FileA','Version3','4.1.2016')
,('UserA','FileA','Version4','5.1.2016')
,('UserB','FileA','Version2','3.1.2016');

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS SortNr
          ,*
    FROM @tbl 
)
SELECT *
FROM Numbered
WHERE SortNr<=2
```

The result

```
1   UserA   FileA   Version4    2016-01-05
2   UserA   FileA   Version3    2016-01-04
1   UserB   FileA   Version2    2016-01-03
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable(UserId VARCHAR(50),FileId VARCHAR(50), [Version] VARCHAR(50),[Date] DATE);
INSERT INTO #MyTable 
VALUES
     ('UserA','FileA','Version1','1.1.2016')
    ,('UserA','FileA','Version2','2.1.2016')
    ,('UserA','FileA','Version3','2.1.2016')
    ,('UserA','FileA','Version3','3.1.2016')
    ,('UserA','FileA','Version3','4.1.2016')
    ,('UserA','FileA','Version4','5.1.2016')
    ,('UserB','FileA','Version2','3.1.2016')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId,FileId,[Version] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS LatestVersion,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId,FileId ORDER BY [Date] DESC ) AS VersionCount           
    FROM #MyTable 
    WHERE [Date] < '1-APR-2016'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE LatestVersion = 1
    AND VersionCount <= 2
```

It returns,

```
UserA   FileA   Version3    2016-03-01  1   1
UserA   FileA   Version2    2016-02-01  1   2
UserB   FileA   Version2    2016-03-01  1   1
```